# CSS selector last row from main table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table inside a table, and I want to fill the background of the last row of table 1 only — not table 2.

```
<style> 
#test tr:last-child
{
  background:#ff0000;
}
</style>

<table border="1" width="100%" id="test">
<tr>
 <td>
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>table 2</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr> 

<tr><td>table 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>table 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>table 1</td></tr>

</table>
```

With my CSS, I'm coloring both last rows of table1 and table2.

Comment: Add a class or unique id attribute to delineate the two tables.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Your tables should have as immediate children just `tbody` and `thead` elements, with the rows within*. So, amend the HTML to be:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="test">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>table 2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr><td>table 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>table 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>table 1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then amend your selector slightly to this:

```css
#test > tbody > tr:last-child { background:#ff0000; }
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/dQJRS/). That makes use of the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors), which:

> ...separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first.

So, you are targeting only direct children of `tbody` elements that are themselves direct children of your `#test` table.

## Alternative solution

The above is the neatest solution, as you don't need to over-ride any styles. [The alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/vA36V/) would be to stick with your current set-up, and over-ride the background style for the inner table, like this:

```css
#test tr:last-child { background:#ff0000; }
#test table tr:last-child { background:transparent; }
```

* It's not mandatory but most (all?) browsers will add these in, so it's best to make it explicit. As @BoltClock states in the comments:

> ...it's now set in stone in HTML5, so for a browser to be compliant it basically must behave this way.

Comment: If you don't specify a `TBODY`, the client will insert one. And if you don't use a `THEAD` or `TFOOT`, the selectors `#test>tbody>tr:last-child` and `#test tr:last-child` will select the same row, with the latter one having a lower specificity.

Comment: @feeela: Except there's an inner table - the former selector will not match the `tr:last-child` within that table. That said, you're right in that there is no need to explicitly add `tbody` tags to the markup.

Comment: @JackPoint - yep, sorry - I missed the second `>` initially. Updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: @BoltClock: is there any reason *not* to add in `tbody`? I guess I just feel more comfortable making it explicit, to avoid this exact situation whereby my selector(s) don't target what I was expecting because they have been added silently.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez: There is no reason *not* to do so, but what I'm saying is simply: if you have a single `tbody` for all your rows then it makes no difference in behavior whether or not you do (and this behavior is generally reliable). It's definitely a good practice to specify it though, especially when it comes to semantics.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez: ... well, unless performance is so critical that omitting the tags would boost load times significantly, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @BoltClock: makes sense, cheers. For anyone (like me) who didn't know, the behaviour of adding in the `tbody` does appear to be consistent cross-browser (quickly tested in IE 8/9/10, Chrome & FF).

Comment: Yep, and as a matter of fact it's now set in stone in HTML5, so for a browser to be compliant it basically *must* behave this way.

Comment: Thank you guys! Nice explanation, it helped me also!